# Android push notification opening is not counting

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush-android

I have an app set up for iOS and Android, and both are working well except for 1 thing, the android app is not counting when the user opens the notification, then MarketingCloud does not take that into the % of opens.

Is there an specific setup that we need to do, or an specific line that I might have missed on the docs that does the trick?

Comment: What version of the SDK?  Did you enable analytics in the SdkConfig used to initialize the SDK?

Comment: 5.3, not sure how to enable the analytics...

Comment: using this one: setAnalyticsEnabled(true) I presume...

Comment: Yes.  Set that to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have `setAnalyticsEnabled(true)` in the `MarketingCloudConfig` that you're providing to the `init()` method of the SDK.

Comment: do you know an average of how long it takes to these numbers update?it's been like more than a few minutes and still 0%

Comment: IDK if the issue still persists, but there was an issue in the recent past that made those statistics not show up for ~6 hours.