# iOS Push Notification - Not marked as Open

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-ios

Currently having a problem where the push notification "open" count does not increment for iOS devices.

Both ETAnalytics and PIAnalytics has a value of true in the JSON Configuration file.

The analytics implementation on the MarketingCloudSDK iOS (v6.1.4) is also followed.

The current MarketingCloudSDK version that the app is currently using is v6.0.0

I was able to resolve this issue on Android devices by following the recommendation on this StackExchange Post: [Android push notification opening is not counting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212591/android-push-notification-opening-is-not-counting)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have implemented everything from https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/analytics/analytics.html then it should be working.  Note: analytics are not sent until the application goes into the background.  Note: if you swipe to close the application then analytics will not be sent until the app is opened and properly put into the background.

Comment: I've added logs to my app to have better visibility on what is happening. Based on logs collected, the didReceiveNotificationResponse method is being executed. I am also getting values for response.notification.request. After setting the app into a background state, I called sfmc_notificationRequest when moving to foreground, Based on my logs sfmc_notificationRequest is empty. Does that mean that the SDK was not informed of the notification which is why the open count does not increment ?

Comment: Happening to our iOS app as well. We integrated the MarketingCloudSDK to our project late last year using SDK version 6.0.0. We were able to see push notifications marked as "Open" before, however, our client reported recently that the number of notifications marked as "Open" is only 0.01%, whereas Android recorded 3%. We also implemented event tracking using Google Analytics when a screen is opened via push notification, and iOS recorded 2.2%. I implemented the `setNotificationRequest` function and `etanalytics` is set to true, so I don't understand why it no longer works.

Comment: @BillMote should we set `etanalytics` and `pianalytics` for this to work? Or is it enough to implement the `[[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setNotificationRequest:response.notification.request]` function?

Comment: @Anon2901 you must call sfmc_setNotificationRequest (sfmc_notificationRequest is a _getter_) with the data from the notification when it comes in via userNotificationCenter:didReceive:withCompletionHandler: (indicating a notification was tapped). As Bill mentioned, analytics are sent when the app goes to the background (after being opened from a push) - and if a user "swipes to close" the app (where they're really force-quitting it) those analytics will not be recorded in MC. You'd be surprised how many users do that, thinking it beneficial.

Comment: @AnnaFortuna specficially, you should set `etanalytics` to true in your configuration. the PI version is for predictive intelligence, a feature of Marketing Cloud you may optionally have purchased.

Comment: @BrianM.Criscuolo thanks for the clarification. I find it weird that the MarketingCloudSDK won't record the data when the app was closed by the user. I thought it will be more like Firebase wherein the data is recorded and the SDK will attempt to send it to the back-end when the app becomes active again. Anyway, if that's how it works, we'll just have to keep that in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnnaFortuna we are in the process of reviewing the analytic sending process in hopes of optimizing it a good bit in the future. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: i have the same error
[Questions Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/393448/how-can-i-send-analytic-event-about-push-open-in-android-sdk)